What is the induced smooth covering map $F_0^*E\times I\rightarrow H^*E$?
Let $F_0,F_1:M\rightarrow N$, be smoothly homotopic maps, and $E\rightarrow N$ a smooth vector bundle over $N$. Then by the homotopy lifting property there exists a bundle morphism $\tilde{H}:F_0^*E\times I\rightarrow E$ that makes the necessary diagram commute.
Now, in showing that $F_0^*E\cong F_1^*E$, we say that there is an induced isomorphism of pull back bundles $\tilde{G}:F_0E^*\times I\rightarrow H^*E$ because of some abstract nonsense. Is this map actually what I think it is though? i.e. we have that:
$$F_0^*E\times I=\{((x,p),t):(x,p)\in F_0^*E, t\in I\}$$
and:
$$H^*E=\{((x,t),p)\in M\times I\times E:H(x,t)=\pi(p)\}$$
So is $\tilde G$ literally the map:
\begin{align}
\tilde{G}((x,p),t)=((x,t),p)?
\end{align}
It makes the diagram commute but it's such a simple map I'm a little confused.
Edit:
Ok I wrote down the wrong diagram, that is my bad for sure.
I think the map is given instead by:
$\tilde{G}((x,p),t)=((x,t),\tilde{H}((x,p),t)$
This actually makes the diagrams commute, but how do we show this is map is an isomorphism of vector bundles then?

That can't be it. For this to be well-defined, you'd have to have $H(x,t)=\pi(p)$, but you instead have $F_0(x)=\pi(p)$.

@Thorgott what do you mean?

I mean your $\tilde{G}$ is not well-defined.

@Thorgott I meant what do you mean I have $F_0(x)=\pi(p)$? Like in what diagram.

That's definitionally what $(x,p)\in F_0^{\ast}E$ implies.

I understand that, but $F_0^*E\times I$ is a vector bundle over $M\times I$ with projection map given by $\pi_M\times \text{Id}_I$, sending the point $((x,p),t)$ to $(x,t)$.

I'm not sure how that relates to my point? Apologies if I'm being dense.

I'm saying that what the map I wrote down makes the fibre product/pullback diagram commute so how can it not be well defined?

@Thorgott do you know how to see that $\tilde{G}$ is an isomorphism for all $t$?

Sorry for the late reply. You got the right map now. The map $\tilde{G}$ is an isomorphism of vector bundles if and only if it is an isomorphism of vector spaces fiber-wise if and only if $\tilde{H}$ is an isomorphism fiber-wise and the latter should be true by construction, which is of course the hard part of the proof.
